# How to multiply two rows in a 2d array?

Tags: python

```
table=[]
rows=int(input("Enter number of rows: "))
col=int(input("Enter number of columns: "))
for i in range(rows):
    array=[]
    for i in range(col):
        array.append(int(input("Enter element row wise")))
    table.append(array)
print(table)
c=[]
for a in range(rows):
    for b in range(col):
        list_multiple=[a*b]
        array.append(c)
    table.append(array)
print(table)
```

I had to ask the user to input a matrix(2d array) and then print it and then multiply the first and last row of the list. I have made the program but can't manage to multiply the rows. However i have managed to print the matrix correctly.

Comment: Can you give some sample input and expected output?

Comment: @schwobaseggl like for suppose the user inputs: [[2,4,7,8], [3,5,0,0], [1,2,3,0]]  so my output should be first the same array should be printed than the multiplied array that is [2,8,21,0]. the output should be `[[2,4,7,8], [3,5,0,0], [1,2,3,0]] [2,8,21,0]`

Comment: You have just repeated the array

Comment: Each of those looks identical to me. Where does any multiplication happen?

Comment: sorry typing error

Comment: Are you multiplying the array ```x``` times

Comment: Why multiplying only the first list  with the last list ? Nothing to do with ```[3, 5, 0, 0]``` ?

Comment: @Metapod that's what i need to do why are you concerned?

Comment: @Jorge Because it can change the implementation. BTW seems like i didn't read your last update (" multiply the first and last row of the list"), so my question is now useless.

Comment: @Metapod :)    hmmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid `zip`, you can try this:

```
c = [table[0][i] * table[-1][i] for i in range(col)]
```

Or equivalent to:

```
c = []
for i in range(col):
    c.append(table[0][i] * table[-1][i])

Input:  [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
Output: [7, 16, 27]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following, `zip`ping the first and last row:

```
table = [[2,4,7,8], [3,5,0,0], [1,2,3,0]] 

mult = [a*b for a, b in zip(table[0], table[-1])]
table.append(mult)

table
# [[2, 4, 7, 8], [3, 5, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3, 0], [2, 8, 21, 0]]
```

Comment: You can also do ```table.append([a*b for a, b in zip(table[0], table[-1])])```

Comment: is there any other way except zip like just by using nested loop?

Comment: ```zip``` takes elements from similar index and returns them in a tuple. You can do ```table.append([table[0][i]*table[-1][j] for i in range(len(table[0])))```

Comment: Nested loops always do some cartesian product type action: *"combine every x from list1 with every y from list2"*. Nested loops do **not** achieve pair-wise iteration. Think about it: only one iteration is happening when you collect the products.

Comment: @schwobaseggl okay bro got it

Comment: @schwobaseggl I would've accepted your answer but i didn't want to use zip in my code so i accepted the second answer don't mind

Comment: @Jorge All good :D